# ERROR HANDLING OF CHARACTER DATA TYPE IN C PROGRAMMING

Tags: c, error-handling

If the user would enter an invalid input, the program will ask the question again until the user enters a valid input. The code below performs it however, it executes the command twice:

```
void error_checking(){
        char input;
        printf("Enter letters from a to e");
        scanf("%c", &input);
        if((input<102) || (input>96)){
             printf("Valid input");
        } else {
             error_checking():
        }
int main(){
        error_checking();
}
```

Comment: Have a look at your OR logic

Comment: input>96 && input<102 includes [a,e].

Comment: Side note: 'a' is easier to read than an int constant

Comment: You could also remove the SHOUTING from the title

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
scanf(" %c", &input);
       ^^^
```

instead of

```
scanf("%c", &input);
       ^^
```

Otherwise the function scanf will read the new line character '\n' that corresponds to the pressed key Enter.

Also you firgot the closing brace of the function.

And it is a bad idea to use magic numbers like

```
if((input<102) || (input>96)){
```

And at least you have ti write

```
if((input<102) && (input>96)){
```